# Problems upgrading to Python 3.3 and setting up Django

Tags: python, apt, django

I'm new to Linux and am trying to set up Python / Django on my machine!  I installed Python 3.3 from the source file and it was compiled into `/usr/local/bin`. Then I created a symbolic link between `/usr/bin/python` and `/usr/local/bin/python3`, so that whenever I invoke python from the command line it uses the latest version.

Now I am trying to install MySQL Python and I got the following output:

```
apt-get install python-mysqldb

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python-mysqldb is already the newest version.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  apt-listchanges python-apt
Suggested packages:
  python-glade2 python-gtk2 python-apt-dbg python-vte python-apt-doc
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apt-listchanges python-apt
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 142 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/394 kB of archives.
After this operation, 250 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/apt-listchanges", line 28, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ImportError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?  Or any tips on how to clean up this install (if this one is too broken)?

Comment: "I installed Python 3.3 from the source file" -- why? Not sure which OS you're on, but backports should be available and make life a lot easier. Ubuntu 12.04 PPA providing Python 3.3 is [here](https://launchpad.net/~python-dev/+archive/ppa?field.series_filter=precise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Way too many packages in Debian still rely on Python 2.x. As a result, almost everyone needs Python 2.x to be installed.

Usually, the following is done to have both Python 2.x and 3.x:

- `/usr/bin/python` refers to a Python 2.x binary
- `/usr/bin/python3` refers to a Python 3.x binary

To see what is the currently installed version of Python on your machine, run:

```
ls -l /usr/bin/python*
```

(results in e.g. `/usr/bin/python2.7`)

To remove the symlink: `rm -i /usr/bin/python`

To create the symlink: `ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python`

Comment: More specifically, Django only has experimental support for Python 3: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/install/#can-i-use-django-with-python-3

Comment: thanks so much -- that fixed it. i think it was too early for me to start using python 3.x